# How to color data on the plot through the gradient depending on how high the curve representing the data is?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, legend

I have a data in the data frame format (140 observations for 34 variables).

Example of the data:

```
   Time Variable Value
    0.3.   2.      0.001
    2.     2.      0.006
    5.     2.      0.007
    7.5.   2       0.01 
   ..........................
    0.3.   3.      0.003
    2.     3.      0.005
    5.     3.      0.009
    7.5.   3       0.02
```

If I plot it by command `ggplot(data = melted, aes(x=Time, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_line()`, it looks like this.
[image: Plot of data]

How to color these lines in a way that the highest line would be, for example, purple and the lowest would red through a constant gradient (like a rainbow)? How to use any other pallets and also show the gradient from highest to lowest curve? How to put pretty legend on a plot?

Thank you very much!

Comment: please try to give a minimal working example with your question, and to focus on one specific question. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how an example dataset could look like:

```
Time <- 1:100

df <- rbind(data.frame(Time = Time,variable = 1,value = as.numeric(Time>20)),
            data.frame(Time = Time,variable = 3,value = as.numeric(Time>20)*2),
            data.frame(Time = Time,variable = 2,value = as.numeric(Time>20)*3))
```

It looks like that:

[image]

You then create a variable maxvalue that gives the maximum value of each group, and use a continuous gradient colouring:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(maxval = max(value,na.rm = T))%>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Time, y=value, color=maxval,group = maxval)) + 
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "C")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

For various option of gradient, see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. 
It says 
Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more what this code does?

Comment: I would need an example dataset, and you should provide it in your question. It can be simple fake data that mimic your real data

Comment: I provided the example. Please, let me know if it's enough or I should do something else. Thank you!

Comment: See my edits. The example you provided is not a proper example: I cannot use it to reproduce a graph similar to yours, so I cannot use it to answer your question. I did provide an example dataset in my answer, please try do something similar for your futur questions